# How to get response from webrequest with login

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, response

I want to get a response from the web, but the response I get is not what I expected, How can I login by using HttpWebRequest?

My Code :

```
public static void CobaData()
{
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072; //[0] Access

        Uri uri = new Uri(AppConfig.HostName);
        CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Accept = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);

        // authentication
        string user = AppConfig.UserName;
        string pass = AppConfig.Password;
        string auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(user + ":" + pass));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

        // response.
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        cookies = response.Cookies;

        HttpWebRequest fileRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(AppConfig.HostName);
        fileRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        fileRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
        fileRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";

        HttpWebResponse fileResponse = (HttpWebResponse)fileRequest.GetResponse();

        string responseStr = "";

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileResponse.GetResponseStream());
        responseStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseStr);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = string.Format("{0}\r\n{1}", ex.ToString(), ex.Trace());
        Sing.Me.Text.Say("err", "{0}", s);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

**Response received :**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/scripts/ric/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>New Token Landing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "GET");
form.setAttribute("id","csrfTokenForm");
form.setAttribute("action", "\/");
hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "csrfToken");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "k3r632apu5ah76mcojqexyk62mshiy4h");
form.appendChild(hiddenField);
document.body.appendChild(form);
if(history.pushState) {
history.pushState(null, document.title, '\/?csrfToken=k3r632apu5ah76mcojqexyk62mshiy4h');}$(document).ready(function(){$('#csrfTokenForm').submit();})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

for the response obtained like this, so only part of the code is obtained.

I would appreciate if someone can tell me what I'm missing.
sorry my english is not good, thank you,

Comment: Please do not post pictures of the code or response. Rather, post the code/response here to get better suggestions.

Comment: Looks like the remote site is expecting the operating client to understand and execute JavaScript. That's going to be a fun one.